# TableViewCell background color is disabled when table view is scrolled

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibackgroundcolor

In my application, I have a tableView, I changed the background color of cell when it is selected, I wrote that code as

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

The problem is When I scrolled the tableView, the background color of cell is disabled, the white color is not visible means the background color effect is removed. The table view reused the cell when scrolled out so the cell background effect is removed. I know where I get the problem but I don't know how to handle this problem and keep the background color of selected cell as white even the table view is scrolled. Please tell me solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change the background of selected rows would be to change the `selectedBackgorundView` when you create the cell. That way, you wouldn't need to handle `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = v; // Set a white selected background view. 
    }
    // Set up the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"foo";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I need to change the background color of cell only when cell is selected.

Comment: @smily It will change the background color of the cells only when they are selected. This is because you are assigning a different view to the cell if the cell is selected and then iOS takes care of switching the views based on if the cell is selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, because cells get reused. So your backgroundColor will probably get overwritten as soon, as the cell gets reused.

You should use the cell backgroundView. Exactly as Pulkit wrote already.

Comment: Thanks jayvee but in which method, selectedBackgroundView for cell has to set? didSelectRow:.. or cellForRow:.. ?

Comment: please show us your complete cellForRow: implementation. Then we can help.